# Wrong implementation of Oracle Java ConcurrentHashMap?

Tags: java, oracle, java-8, concurrenthashmap

I am testing [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) on Oracle's Java 8 implementation:

```
ConcurrentMap<String, String> concurrentMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
String result = concurrentMap.computeIfAbsent("A", k -> "B");
System.out.println(result);  // "B"
result = concurrentMap.putIfAbsent("AA", "BB");
System.out.println(result);  // null
```

The [Javadoc of `computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) does say that

> **Implementation Requirements:**
>
> The default implementation is equivalent to the following steps for this map, then returning the current value or null if now absent:
>
> ```
> if (map.get(key) == null) {
>     V newValue = mappingFunction.apply(key);
>     if (newValue != null)
>         return map.putIfAbsent(key, newValue);
> }
> ```

It said *then returning the current value or null if now absent*. So shouldn't it be returning `null`? Given that `putIfAbsent` is also returning `null`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: I don't see that this is contradictory with the specification at all

Comment: The pseudocode in the Javadoc is meant for illustration.  The actual implementation, while similar, handles your case properly.

Comment: The documentation has been fixed in java 9.  See [the bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8174087) and the [fixed version of the javadoc](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-)

Comment: @Misha Thanks for pointing that out, wonderful. No more debate :)

Comment: @Misha: thanks, I added it to the answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The code example of `ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent` is not reflecting the actual intention, most likely a mistake caused by the non-intuitive behavior of `putIfAbsent`, while the implementation obeys the documented intention. This has been reported in [JDK-8174087](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8174087)
 and [fixed in Java 9](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-)

Note that the contract for [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) is

> #### Implementation Requirements:
>
> The default implementation is equivalent to the following steps for this map, then returning the current value or null if now absent:
>
> ```
> if (map.get(key) == null) {
>     V newValue = mappingFunction.apply(key);
>     if (newValue != null)
>         map.put(key, newValue);
> }
> ```

omitting the `return` statement. But clearly says

> #### Returns:
>
> the current (existing or computed) value associated with the specified key, or null if the computed value is null

It is the documentation of [`ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) that tries to incorporate the concurrency aspect, falling for the non-inuitive behavior of `putIfAbsent`:

> #### Implementation Requirements:
>
> The default implementation is equivalent to the following steps for this map, then returning the current value or null if now absent:
>
> ```
> if (map.get(key) == null) {
>     V newValue = mappingFunction.apply(key);
>     if (newValue != null)
>         return map.putIfAbsent(key, newValue);
> }
> ```

but it still says

> #### Returns:
>
> the current (existing or computed) value associated with the specified key, or null if the computed value is null

and the documented intention should have precedence over a code example. Note that the actual [`default` implementation of `ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.java#318) is in line with the documented intention:

> ```
> @Override
> default V computeIfAbsent(K key,
>         Function<? super K, ? extends V> mappingFunction) {
>     Objects.requireNonNull(mappingFunction);
>     V v, newValue;
>     return ((v = get(key)) == null &&
>             (newValue = mappingFunction.apply(key)) != null &&
>             (v = putIfAbsent(key, newValue)) == null) ? newValue : v;
> }
> ```

So [the implementation of `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.util.function.Function%29) does conform to the documented intention of both, `ConcurrentMap.computeIfAbsent` and `Map.computeIfAbsent` regarding the returned value and is also equivalent to the `default` implementation provided by the interfaces.

For completeness, the `default` implementation of [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/Map.java#Map.computeIfAbsent%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.util.function.Function%29) is

> ```
> default V computeIfAbsent(K key,
>         Function<? super K, ? extends V> mappingFunction) {
>     Objects.requireNonNull(mappingFunction);
>     V v;
>     if ((v = get(key)) == null) {
>         V newValue;
>         if ((newValue = mappingFunction.apply(key)) != null) {
>             put(key, newValue);
>             return newValue;
>         }
>     }
>
>     return v;
> }
> ```

Comment: TL;DR that's just a bad example in the documentation?

Comment: @Eugene: exactly.

Comment: Thanks. However, besides the code example, the doc also said above the code: "then returning the current value or null if now absent". Which contradicts to its behaviour "returning the current value or new value if now absent".

Comment: @user1589188: “*the current value*” is the value stored in the map when the method returns, which might be either “*existing or computed*”, as stated. “*if now absent*” means “if the mapping has been removed upon return”, which can only happen if your function returned `null`, so in that case, the returned value is also identical to the computed value.

Comment: @Holger I can't agree. As `computeIfAbsent` does not remove entry even if the computed/new value is null (unlike `compute` or `merge`). So "if now absent" is referring to the state before calling the method.

Comment: @user1589188: it doesn’t matter whether there is an entry mapping to `null` or no entry. In either case `computeIfAbsent` (note “compute—if—absent”) will evaluate your function and use the returned value. If your function returns `null`, the next `computeIfAbsent` for the same key will again evaluate the function (consider the key as absent). In case of `ConcurrentMap`s which don’t allow `null` values, returning `null` *does* even imply that there will be no mapping stored. It wasn’t be removed, though, simply because there was no mapping to begin with…

Comment: @Holger there won't be a case that before calling the method there is a current value and after calling the method the value becomes absent. It should not even try to compute if there is a current value to begin with. So saying "if now absent" would be meaningless if it is referring to the state after as "it has always been absent" the whole time. Anyway, they seem to have realised their fault and now fixed in java 9, which is great :)

Comment: @user1589188: “if now absent” does *not* imply “if it became absent”. And the phrase “*Returns: the current (existing or computed) value* …” is quiet clear. There is room for improvement, indeed, but I still don’t understand where your quibbling is heading at. It looks like you *want* to misunderstand that specification…

Answer (score 0):

Actual code from javadoc:

```
 if (map.get(key) == null) {
 V newValue = mappingFunction.apply(key);
     if (newValue != null)
         map.put(key, newValue);  // <-
     }
 }
```

As you can see there is no `return` keyword in the marked line.

Section "return" also says:

> **Returns:**
>   the current (**existing or computed**) value associated with the specified key, or null if the computed value is null

Comment: Hummm, what version is yours? Mine has return exactly as I have copied. I am on 8u60.

Comment: I have 8_05, 65 and 91. They all have the same javadoc. Here it is: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: Ah I see. You are reading from Map. But I am referring to ConcurrentMap http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-