# Execution of `mappingFunction` in ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent and ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfPresent

Tags: java, multithreading, java-8

I am trying to see actual Java documentation describing the behavior of how many times `mappingFunction` can be called when passed to  `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent` and `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfPresent` methods.

The Javadoc of `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent` seems pretty clear in saying that the `mappingFunction` will be executed at most once:

**Javadoc for `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent`**

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value, attempts
>   to compute its value using the given mapping function and enters it
>   into this map unless null. The entire method invocation is performed
>   atomically, **so the function is applied at most once per key**. Some
>   attempted update operations on this map by other threads may be
>   blocked while computation is in progress, so the computation should be
>   short and simple, and must not attempt to update any other mappings of
>   this map.

But the Javadoc for `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfPresent` does not say anything about how many times `mappingFunction` can be executed:

**Javadoc for `ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfPresent`**

> If the value for the specified key is present, attempts to compute a
>   new mapping given the key and its current mapped value. The entire
>   method invocation is performed atomically. Some attempted update
>   operations on this map by other threads may be blocked while
>   computation is in progress, so the computation should be short and
>   simple, and must not attempt to update any other mappings of this map.

By looking at the source code they both look like that `mappingFunction` will be executed at most once. But I would really like to see actual documentation guaranteeing that behavior.

Is there such a documentation?

Comment: this would not be the first time something is not correct in the documentation... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46272108/wrong-implementation-of-oracle-java-concurrenthashmap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the documentation for [`ConcurrentMap#computeIfPresent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html#computeIfPresent-K-java.util.function.BiFunction-), we see the following:

> The default implementation is equivalent to performing the following steps for this map:

```
for (V oldValue; (oldValue = map.get(key)) != null; ) {
    V newValue = remappingFunction.apply(key, oldValue);
    if ((newValue == null)
        ? map.remove(key, oldValue)
        : map.replace(key, oldValue, newValue))
     return newValue;
 }
 return null;
```

Even though the documentation doesn't explicitly say that the remapping function will only be executed once, the equivalent code that the documentation provides makes that clear.

**Note**: Keep in mind that:

> When multiple threads attempt updates, map operations and the **remapping function may be called multiple times**.

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Thanks. But that code is just for documenting how implementation might use `remappingFunction` and is not thread safe, is actual quite different then the code used in `ConcurrentHashMap` and does not give clear answer as to how many times `remappingFunction` might be called in actual multi threaded implementation.

Comment: I'm not sure if you saw the most recent edit, but the documentation states "When multiple threads attempt updates, map operations and the **remapping function may be called multiple times**."

Comment: Yes, but is it from actual documentation or is just your own opinion. Because `computeIfAbsent` updates map but also guarantees that "remapping function" wont be called more then once.

Comment: It's from the documentation!  Read the link in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I was looking for.

Comment: @JacobG. sounds like a bug in the documentation to me, as such, you should highlight that as the very first sentence, in bold. Or better, open a ticket and link it to the answer

Comment: @Eugene I can’t see, where the documentation is wrong. In contrast, I can’t follow the logic of this answer. It shows a piece of code that clearly contains a loop, followed by the contradicting statement that this code made it “clear” that the function is “executed once”.

Comment: @Holger oh god thank you, I was just reading this question/answer after seeing the other one from you and could not make any sense in either my comment or the answer...